# Specified cast is not valid - accessing WebBrowser in different UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I"m stumped on how my program is working.  I'm using threading (was told to do so from another Stack Overflow answer) in order for the `webBrowser2.Navigate(Url);` in `TestScenarios()` to run asynchronously inside of the `while` loop in `GetScenarios()`.  This all works fine.

Now, I added a chunk of code to inject and run some javascript inside of the `WebBrowser` control.  However, every time I call the `HtmlElement head = webBrowser2.Document`.... line, I get the "Specified cast is not valid error."

I know this error has something to do with the `WebBrowser` control being accessed in a separate UI thread, and not being able to work that way, but I'm confused on exactly what that means and how I can fix it.

If you need more context just comment.

```
public void GetScenarios()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while() {
            ...
            TestScenarios();
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    TestScenarios() {
        ...
        Action action = () =>
                {
                    webBrowser2.Tag = signal;
                    webBrowser2.Navigate(Url);
                    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
                    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
                };
                webBrowser2.Invoke(action);
                signal.WaitOne();
        ...
        //Run some javascript on the WebBrowser control
        HtmlElement head = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                    HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser2.Document.CreateElement("script");
                    IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
                    element.text = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }";
                    head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
                    webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing this problem because you are accessing the elements of webBrowser before the document is even loaded. You should move this code

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                    HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser2.Document.CreateElement("script");
                    IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
                    element.text = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }";
                    head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
                    webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
```

To

```
WebBrowserDocumentCompleted
```

event.

Answer (score 1):

First off... you should really step through it in the debugger and figure out what the object you are trying to cast is... this doesn't seem like a threading issue.

Based on your error `webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0]` is not convertible to an `HtmlElement`.

You could also try something like this to see what the object is...

```
var head = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0] as HtmlElement;
if (head == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(head);  // output the object type somehow
}
```

Comment: Couple of things here. Firstly if not null webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0] is convertible to htmlelement. Secondly shouldn't if (head == null) be if (head != null)

Comment: @EhsanUllah No you are trying to cast it to HtmlElement but head == null if that fails... in which case you want to write out what the object actually is in order to troubleshoot it.

Comment: what will be typeof(head) then?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by wrapping the JS scripting chunk in:

```
webBrowser2.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
     //......
}
```

Comment: this may have fixed your error temporarily but is not a permanent solution.

Comment: Check @EhsanUllah 's answer... this seems likely to be the root cause.

Comment: Why not?  How is this not permanent?  What problems am I overseeing?

Comment: Okay will check out his answer.